# Telerik Command LaunchNewBrowser() displays a blank empty page

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, silverlight, telerik, telerik-test-studio

We are running Silverlight tests through NUnit on Internet Explorer.The webpage is hosted on a localhost. There is a testcase where it navigates to the Webpage and tries to login to the site. 
A setup project is which will have an exe file which calls all these test cases. If I install this setup project on my development machine and runs the exe as an administrator the tests are passed. But if I install the same setup project in a new machine which has telerik Teststudio, .net 4.6 , silverlight installed, the command times out at the line
        `Manager.LaunchNewBrowser(BrowserType.InternetExplorer);`

and hence its not able to navigate to the url

```
ActiveBrowser.NavigateTo(BaseUrl);
```

Please note that i have not installed VS in this new machine. My requirement is i should be able to run these test cases without VS. 
Telerik version is 152.9.23.0.

Answer (score 0):

Your runner may not be able to connect to the newly opened browser and hence the next step which is a navigation is not working. You can try the option for connecting to the new browser window as below:

Manager.LaunchNewBrowser(BrowserType.InternetExplorer,true);

By this coded line, your telerik runner is connected to IE and now you can put your step: ActiveBrowser.NavigateTo(BaseUrl);